# A word for someone who doesn't put up a fight in a bad situation

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to describe how the people in William Blakes' world don't do too much to break free from the control of the church and state

Comment: Are you perhaps wondering why there was a Revolution in France, but not in Gt Britain? It is a very well-documented subject by historians. The essential reason that republicans and radicals in Britain did not overturn society and government was that proportionately there were far fewer of them in Britain than there were in France. However many radicals did attempt a great deal, most notably people like Thomas Payne. There were many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general word would be ***submissive***.

From [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/submissive):

> **submissive** *adj*
>
> 1. of, tending towards, or indicating submission, humility, or servility
>
> **submissive** *adj*.
>
> 1. inclined or ready to submit; unresistingly or humbly obedient.
> 2. marked by or indicating submission.

Answer (score 0):

milksop ~ a person who is indecisive and lacks courage.

pacifist ~ a person who believes that war and violence are unjustifiable.